# How to work on a program from any computer that is connected to the internet?

Tags: coding

I apologize if this question is a duplicate but I am having trouble phrasing my question. I am a beginner and for the last months I have been working on a Java program. Sometimes I work on the go from my laptop and sometimes I work at home from my desktop. This means that if I am done writing some code in the desktop then I have to upload all the files to Google Drive and then download them again when I work on my laptop and vice versa. I am switching computers more often and it's becoming tedious to have to do this uploading and downloading to Google Drive all the time (open browser, delete old files from computer, download new files from Drive, move files from Download folder to the program folder).

Is there something more convenient? Something that I can run from the terminal that will immediately save my files to some server and then allow me to pull them from the server to any computer?

Comment: "Source control" is the search term.

Comment: Yes, you will have yo do that (upload and download files). However, there are better approaches aluded to by @Telastyn.

Comment: I would totally agree with you @Telastyn, this was my issue before, luckily I found out about `git`

Comment: You might want to make your program [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) and to publish it on http://github.com/

Comment: In your situation, I use DropBox. However, if relying on auto-synch like DropBox, make sure that your IDE is regularly saving files (automatic, by timer), or you will one day inevitability walk away from some unsaved code & start working on an older version at another location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem with working on different pc's on the same code/project?**

This issue was also my problem before, luckily I found out about **[revision control systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)**..

I used **[git](http://git-scm.com/)** as my tool so whenever I modify my code to my pc at home, as I continue to code at my office, I could just update it flawlessly using `git pull` and when I finish updating my code I will just update the repo by `git push origin master` and so..

You can also modify your code in your workplace and in home pc with different codes and just merge the codes later..

there are other tools like this: svn, cvs, etc.. but I would suggest GIT...

for more info on git, visit this [link](http://git-scm.com/about).

Comment: Don't forget to `git push` often, in particular before leaving any place (e.g. office or home)

Answer (score -1):

Make a cloud machine your workstation.
The good: Access it from anywhere.
The bad: never as good as a local desktop.

Or: make a cloud file system your source file system.
The good: No uploading and downloading
The bad: accessing the files is going to be slow.
The bad: you have to maintain duplicate development environments everwhere.

Or: pick your primary desktop. Use VNC or Windows Remote to access it when 
it's not your local desktop.